# Can the content remain centered while the screen size changes?

Tags: javascript, css

First, here's is my rough example: http://demindu.com/sandbox/simple.html

What I'm trying to do:

Create a content div: let's say 400px tall and 700px wide, like the example. The content box has a margin of 50px in each direction. The content div should always be centered both vertically and horizontally, regardless of screen resolution. The black background should extend from the centered content area all the way to the right side of the screen, but not to the left.

The only way I can think of possibly doing this is something using `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight` in JavaScript, but I don't know enough to know if this is even possible.

The amount of blank space above and below the middle section would need to be:
 `window.innerHeight` - height of the div (in this example: 500px [400px box with two 50px margins]) / 2

The blank space to the left of the black bar would need to be:
 `window.innerWidth` - width of the div (in this example: 800px [700px box with two 50px margins]) / 2

My question to you is: **Is this possible in JavaScript? Is this possible somehow with pure CSS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this entirely in CSS with 4-point absolute positioning. You will need two elements:

1. The first item spans from the right of the screen to the center where the content is positioned. This element uses absolute positioning for the top, left, and right coordinates of the element (we can leave bottom unspecified as it's taken care of by the height.)
2. The second item is nested in the former. This item has a fixed width to ensure the content itself remains in the specified width you've chosen. We can also set the height and padding on this object and the parent will inherit it's height. Don't use margins to simulate padding - it can cause cross browser issues when you're just trying to do some positioning tricks as we are here.

So your HTML code would look something like this:

```
    <div id="my_centered_design">
        <div id="my_centered_design_content">
            <p>This is just some example text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And you're CSS would look like this:

```
    div#my_centered_design {
      background: #000;
      margin-left: -400px;
      margin-top: -250px;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
   }

   div#my_centered_design_content {
      background: #333;
      height: 400px;
      /* I think you actually want padding for 
         the effect you're trying to accomplish */
      padding: 50px;
      width: 700px;
   }
```

Essentially this is the same trick as the Joe2Tutorial except we are applying additional positioning rules to adhere the centered element to the right side of the screen.

Comment: Masterful Jim, this works for me completely. The only part I don't understand is the need for the negative margins in the outer DIV, but it works, so that's not too important. Thank you!

Comment: The negative margins are required to actually center the position of the element. See you're setting the top and left to 50%. So that means the top left corner of your element would be exactly at the middle of the viewport. However, you want the center of the element, not the top left corner, to be positioned at the middle of the viewport. So you do this by offsetting the position of the element with negative margins that are exactly 1/2 of the elements height and width.

Answer (score 0):

I think this pure css solution would suit you best: http://www.joe2torials.com/view_tutorial.php?view=37

Comment: That would allow me to place something completely centered on the page, but wouldn't account for the offset created by the background extending all the way to the right but not the left.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick google resulted in this piece of code.

this code does not align a div in the middle. what you actually for your own website is that you put the following div css

.main {
width: 140px;background-color: #252525; float: left;margin-top: 25px; }

inside a table that is aligned to be centered. so, basically you're using the table's centering feature to center your left floated div simply as a content. you're not doing anything through div or css for that matter. the piece of css code you offered doesn't not anything about centering a div in the middle.